# Adding Custom Header to asp.net MVC 4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to add custom headers to asp.net MVC 4 Web API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are talking about HTTP headers. And I am not sure if you want to customize the response or the request. You can do both. Here is a [blog post](http://www.shawnmclean.com/blog/2012/04/asp-net-webapi-same-origin-policy-workaround-using-custom-http-headers/) that shows how to add a custom header in the response using and ActionFilterAttribute. If you are using JQuery ajax to send a request to the Web API you can use the beforeSend event to add a custom header. Here is an example of using it for basic authentication.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        type: _type,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var up = username + ":" + password;
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + up);
        },
        success: _successFunc,
        error: _errorFunc
    });
```

Comment: brilliantly simple response - after a few hours going around in circles, this made my afternoon - especially the link detailing the "Same Origin Policy" and "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" stuff I've been dancing around all day..., this response should be on 10x answers on SO...